# Retrieving reports from iManage based on the Document Name or generating list of documents with document information

Tags: vba, imanage

I extract reports from iManage on daily basis and I was searching macro codes that would automate this process. After much search in various forums, I found this Ed Mozley's link, which I found very helpful to understand about the retrieval process from iManage.

[Saving to iManage with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770259/saving-to-imanage-with-vba)

To retrieve reports from the iManage, Ed mentions using of GetDocument function which has 2 parameters (document number, version number). In my case, however, the document number changes everyday with the updates after day-end process and are always unique.

I would like to know if there is a way to generate the list of documents created on a particular date and that list contains Document Name, Document Number, Version ID, Document Creation Time, Database etc. information. If I could generate the list of documents, I could compare my list of relevant documents with this list and then pull the document numbers and save them in array and create the relevant copies using codes suggested by Ed Mozley.

Or can we create copy of document based on the document name that partially matches with the name of the document available in iManage?

Any advice will of great help.

Thank you
Roshan

Comment: This is not a specific programming question. It looks like a question about a specific application. This is off-topic for StackOverflow. You would be better off asking in a forum dedicated to iManage.

Comment: Thank you HackSlash for your advice. I thought it is a VBA programming question. The code suggested by Ed requires "document number" stored as constant. I tried to work on different functions available for IManDatabase, but due my lack of knowledge, I was getting error. I do not want to wander in different forums as it will violate rules of those forums.

Comment: Please check the help docs for information that will help you write questions that will get answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask